# ABAP HTTP Destination => check whether SSL is enabled

Tags: ssl, https, abap, sap-basis

I have an HTTP destination in an ABAP system (destination type `G`) and send sensitive data to the destination.

Before I send the data, I need to check whether the destination has SSL option enabled.

**UPDATE:** I'm using the destination in `cl_http_client=>create_by_destination(...)`: So, if here is a way to get hold of the protocol, this would be fine as well (I checked interfaces `IF_HTTP_CLIENT` and `IF_HTTP_REQUES`, found nothing..)

Thanks!

Comment: I am not aware of a solution, but what about using SM59 "test"-button and debug the functionality? Maybe it helps you to see how SAP standard does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add select option (or hard coded) for RFC destination for type RFCDES-RFCDEST and check it has configuration as "s=" for field **RFCOPTIONS** in table **RFCDES**. Then use this RFC destination in **HTTP_GET** function (or develop your custom).

Comment: it has none. RFCOPTIONS is `H=host...,N=/path,W=Y,B=N,C=N,E` and turning SSL on/off doesnt change the RFCOPTIONS field in RFCDES table

Comment: it actually is, it was only cut-off in display. `s=Y` means enabled, `s=N` means disabled. Moreover, there is a function module RFCDES2RFCDISPLAY which will convert a row from `RFCDES` to a structure `RFCDISPLAY`, which is used in dialogs in SM59, so it is easier to get the connection between the screen and the data